# Calling a class member function inside definition of the other member function of same class

Tags: c++

What is the method to call a memberfunction of a class inside definition of the other member function of same class?

For Ex:
File:
header.h

```
class A
{
public:
void fn1();
void fn2();
};
```

Now in cpp file:
function.cpp

method1:

```
#include"header.h"
void A::fn1()
{
//function body for fn1()

//What is the way to make a call for fn2()?
//assume I have definition of fn2() above similar to fn1()

fn2();
}
```

method2:

```
#include"header.h"
A obj_A;
void A::fn1()
{
//function body for fn1()

//What is the way to make a call for fn2()?
//assume I have definition of fn2() above similar to fn1()

obj_A.fn2();
}
```

Please clarify which method is correct?

Thanks,
A beginnner in C++.

Answer (score 3):

Both versions are correct, but behave differently. The first version will call the function on the same instance f1 was called on, while the second will always call f2 on obj_A instance.

Comment: I think it would be more accurate to say that both technically work (that is, they generate valid code), but method 2 is incorrect because the function call is made on a different object.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart It's **not** incorrect, it depends on the intend which wasn't clearly worked out by the OP.

Comment: If the original call is `obj_A.fn1();` they will do exactly the same (which could make the unit testing interesting).

Comment: The question says "What is the method to call a memberfunction of a **class** inside definition of the other **member function of same class**?" the "of same class" part says to me that the first function is calling the second one from the context of defining the behavior of the class, rather than calling it on an object. I guess it's subjective though and i see your point.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 is correct.

Method 2 appears to be calling the method on a different instance than the you are making the call from, which is a different behavior. There can be cases where this is what you want but you didn't indicate this was that case.

Are you having issues with the first method?